# 60' underground, 60' wall mounted outlet boxes and 50' attic space. What do I use for each? PVC, EMT or other conduit using 12/2 Romex

Tags: electrical

I have a shop I'm wanting to run power to from my garage main panel.  I need eight 2 gang outlet boxes and one 2 gang switch box.  Outlets will be 20a.  They will have to be surface mounted on wall.  What size sub panel do I need, how many spaces/circuits?  I like to have each wall separate. When running wire in the conduit and the boxes, do I use pvc, emt or other?  I need 60' in attic, 60' underground and 50' on the walls between boxes?  I will have an licensed electrician hook everything up, but I want to do the rest.

Comment: How many square feet is said shop space and what sort of tools are we talking about here? (Woodshop, metalshop/welding, ...?)

Comment: What are your outlets feeding? With the development of electric car chargers "garage" questions leave our heads spinning. In the old days we would say you probably only need a 30A 240v panel but if you're going to the trouble you're better off to install a 60A. Now throw in a Tesla and we are left asking if your whole service is big enough to run 100A to the garage

Comment: GFCI requirements have also added space requirement issues. Many 12 circuit panels are really 6 space panels and they get to 12 by counting tandem breakers. But a garage now requires GFCI protection on most everything, making 1/2 space counting obsolete since GFCI breakers require full spaces. If you have space get double or more the size you think you need.

Comment: Yeah, you'll never hate yourself for getting a 24-space panel. Price difference might buy a couple of lattés but you'll never miss em.  By the way, can't use Romex (NM) outside.  If you're running the whole route in conduit, no need to use cable at all, you can use THWN wires - easier to pull.

Comment: @NoSparksPlease sounds like the _main_ is in the _garage_ and the OP want to run a sub off of that into a _shop_. Otherwise, I agree with you 100%!

Comment: Main panel is in garage.  I want to run romex 12/2 to my shop that is 12x16.  I dont want any extension cords so I want 2 double gang boxes on each wall.  Each at 20a.  
 Primarily a workshop/woodshop.  I have a small 125mig welder I fix small things with.  I'll do maintenance on landscape equipment for my boys business.  Pretty much only need 110v, no 220v.  I need to bury about 60 feet and want to know which is okay to use; sch40 PVC , EMT or something else?  When mounting on the interior of shop walls do I use the same?  PVC or EMT or ??   Do I need conduit in the attic?